# Отключение горячих клавиш Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, hotkeys

Итоговая цель - отключение горячих клавиш в Астра линуксе, но однажды я находил рекомендации, не знаю для какой ОС, которые помогли, но сейчас не могу их найти. По рекомендациям нужно было создать отдельный конфигурационный файл в котором нужно было указать что-то вроде
`"Disable" = горячие клавиши`
Может кто-то в курсе о каком способе идёт речь?

Answer (score 0):

Для астры(1.74) есть возможность настроить горячие клавиши через графику:

Пуск->Панель управления->Рабочий стол->Горячие клавиши Fly.

Если не использовать гуи - конфигурационные файлы хоткеев живут в /usr/share/fly-wm

Какой именно файл Вам нужен - не подскажу, знаю что для пользователя с режимом киоска используется конфига с названием keyshortcutrc.fly-kiosk.

Можете методом высоконаучного тыка выяснить какой из файлов, содержащих в названии "keyshortcutrc" будет полезен в вашем случае.